# Create an array from n copies of subarray in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a more efficient way (or at least pythonic) to stack n copies of a subarray in order to create a new array?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(4)
for i in range(n-1):
    x = hstack((x,arange(4)))
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [34]: x = np.arange(4)

In [35]: np.tile(x,(3,1))
Out[35]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

But be careful -- you may be able to use [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) instead of duplicating the same row over and over.

For example, suppose you have some array of shape (3,4):

```
In [40]: y = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

In [41]: y
Out[41]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

And here is your `x`:

```
In [42]: x = np.arange(4)

In [43]: x
Out[43]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

You can add `x` (whose shape is `(4,)`) with `y` (whose shape is `(3,4)`), and NumPy will automatically "broadcast" `x` to shape (3,4):

```
In [44]: x + y
Out[44]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  4,  6],
       [ 4,  6,  8, 10],
       [ 8, 10, 12, 14]])
```

Compare the result with

```
In [45]: np.tile(x,(3,1)) + y
Out[45]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  4,  6],
       [ 4,  6,  8, 10],
       [ 8, 10, 12, 14]])
```

As you can see, there is no need to `tile` `x` first. In fact, by *not* tiling `x`, you save memory.

Comment: Don't forget advanced indexing and the `index_tricks` module instances. `x[np.c_[[range(x.size)]*n]]` will have the same effect as tiling, assuming `x` is a flat array. (Though it probably still uses more memory than direct broadcasting.)

Comment: Very concise. np.tile() was what I was looking for and the broadcasting solution was what I came here asking for.